# Connecting to Google hosted MySQL using SSL from python

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, google-cloud-sql

Performing a basic test. I have a MySQL DB hosted in Google SQL. No issues using MySQL Workbench via SSL from my local computer. So can confirm that access for local IP is correctly setup.

Here is where I am having a problem. Writing a basic connection test program in Python. The program is making an SSL connection to DB and running a query that returns 6 rows. Code listed below.

```
CNX = mysql.connector.connect(**CONFIG)
cur = CNX.cursor()
cur.execute("select BoroId AS boro_id, BoroName AS boro_name from boro")
for (boro_id, boro_name) in cur:
   print "%s %s" % (boro_id, boro_name)
cur.close()
CNX.close()
```

My issue is that the "for" statement iterates through 0 rows. I do not get any errors. I know the connection part is working and query execution is taking place - on inserting below line after "execute" statement sets value of result_row_count to 6.

```
result_row_count = cur.rowcount
```

Official MySQL document states I should be able to iterate through each of the six rows using "for" statement. Any help appreciated.